# gparted ntfs support on opensuse 12.2 with gnome 3

Tags: gparted, gnome3, ntfs-3g, opensuse-12.2

When I open gparted it shows no ntfs support, informing ntfs-3g and ntfsprogs packages need to be installed in order to provide this support. The packages are already installed, though.

Nobody else seems to be having this problem, I couldn't find anything about it on google.

I'm on an OpenSUSE 12.2 default install using Gnome 3. I'm running 3.7 kernel from kernels repo instead of default 3.4, but I don't think this is related to the problem, since I can still mount and write on ntfs partitions.

Comment: I just found out there's a partition manager included on the default install so I don't really need gparted, but still...

Comment: http://tropenhitze.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/ntfs-3g-default-write-permission-for-users-on-opensuse-11-2/

Comment: but local users are already allowed to mount and write to ntfs partitions by default. Is it because it's set up through fuse or something?